# A Christmas Gift

Tags: knowledge, story, chemistry

Thanksgiving done and Christmas around the corner. Both mom and dad were whispering in the hallways glancing over their shoulders to ensure no one was listening. I knew they were planning something special again this year. I just had to be patient.

A day later I found my first clue! I knew it! I knew something special was coming for Christmas this year!

On the fridge was a note, and it simply said:

> Add together this simple song: La La La
>
> Add together this silly giggle: He He He
>
> The number of Superman's Folly
>
> Now, take your first answer and subtract the second. Finally, add the third.

On the bottom of the note was some really small text. It read:

> Once you figure out your number, come see me for your next clue.

I took the note and back to my room. I sat on my bed pondering. What did this mean? I knew she wouldn't use something past my twelfth grade knowledge, so I thought harder.

As I sat there, I looked around my room and saw it on my wall. The light bulb turned on and I knew what I had to do. I scribbled down some notes on a piece of paper and looked at my answer. Confident I was on the right track, I found my mom.

She looked and grinned and handed me a piece of paper. It read:

> Just know that I'm divisible by three
>
> Make my answer a triplet
>
> When you figure me out you will know where to go

I took my answer and of course I divided it by three. I did the next part of the puzzle and stared.

Would she have used the same logic as before? Or, was this different? I took a wild guess and saw my answer. I smiled and knew what I had to do.

I hopped in my car and dashed to the mall. I ran down the escalator and near a crowd. I could hear my answer echoing in the air and I looked down the way I saw my dad sitting there with a grin on his face and eyes glinting with jolly.

I waited in line and as I approached he smiled. I felt silly going up, but I did anyway. He then began to hand me a piece of paper. Another clue!

It said:

> Mom's first clue have 3 questions. Each question had a number for the answer.
>
> First number: Subtract 144
>
> Second number: Divide by 2
>
> Third number: Subtract 4

I looked at the results and knew what I needed to do. I pulled out my phone and looked them up (I mean, I can't know everything right?). I saw the 3 answers and looked at him quizzically. It just didn't make any sense.

He then said, "Put them together and say it out loud"

As I did this the word formed as I said it. As I did, he handed me a piece of paper with a big number on it! I couldn't believe my eyes. I put it all together and realized what it was for. I started to cry. I gave him a hug and just smiled.

Thanks Dad.

You're welcome son. Make me proud.

What was my gift?

Info:

> I purposely left a tag out as it would make it too easy. Once the answer has been posted, I will add the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:

> College. Well, a check for college really.

Fridge Note:

> These are elements on the periodic table. Thus:
>  1. La La La = 171
>  2. He He He = 6
>  3. Krypton is element 36
>  4. Now, take your first answer and subtract the second. Finally, add the third = 171 - 6 + 36 = 201

Second Note:

> Just know that I'm divisible by three
>  Make my answer a triplet
>  When you figure me out you will know where to go
>  201 / 3 = 67. 67 is Ho on the periodic table, thus ho ho ho. That's why he went to the mall to see his dad as Santa Claus.

Third Note:

> Mom's first clue have 3 questions. Each question had a number for the answer.
>  First number: Subtract 144
>    = 171 - 144 = 27
>  Second number: Divide by 2
>    = 6 / 2 = 3
>  Third number: Subtract 4
>    = 36 - 4 = 32
>  These are: Co Li Ge
>  Said Allowed: College. Basically, they just paid for his college! What a Christmas!!

Comment: Nice! I was inspired to make this as I told my daughter I would pay for her first semester of college :)

Comment: That's awesome @CodeLikeBeaker! :D